# trying to add docker image for frontend vite app

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, vite

so I have working backend and db images within my container and I'm trying to now do the same with the frontend but I'm having a much more difficult time being able to view my app. My impression is that I had to copy over the dist folder created after running vite build. I created an image from my frontend dockerfile and updated my docker-compose file to include the frontend service but when I navigate to 3300 I get a 404. My server is running on 3300 and when I usually run vite it runs a dev server on 3000. I'm also new to using vite which has made this a little more confusing. I've tried messing with ports and which are exposed but have had no luck. had a much easier time containerizing the backend and my db. thanks so much for any help!

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /user/src/app 
WORKDIR /user/src/app
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json", "./"] /user/src/app/
RUN npm ci 
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3300
CMD [ "npm", "run", "server:run" ]
```

Dockerfile-frontend:

```
FROM node:16-alpine
WORKDIR /user/src/app
COPY . .
RUN npm ci
RUN npm run app:build
COPY dist /user/src/app
EXPOSE 3300
CMD ["npm", "run", "app:dev"]
```

Docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'
services:
  #mongo db service
  mongodb:
    container_name: db_container
    image: mongo:latest
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    restart: always
    ports:
      - $MONGODB_DOCKER_PORT:$MONGODB_DOCKER_PORT
    volumes:
      - ./mongodb:/data/db

  #node app service
  app:
    container_name: node_container
    image: sherlogs_app
    build: .
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports: 
      - $NODE_LOCAL_PORT:$NODE_LOCAL_PORT
    volumes:
      - .:/user/src/app
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    depends_on:
      - mongodb

  # frontend container
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend_container
    image: sherlogs/frontend-container
    build: .
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    ports:
      - $FRONTEND_LOCAL_PORT:$FRONTEND_LOCAL_PORT
    volumes:
      - .:/user/src/app
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - app
    
volumes:
  mongodb: {}
```

Comment: you need make a http server, use `vite preview` or nginx server

Answer (score 0):

In your `vite.config.js` file, make sure you add `host: true`. Check out https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html